# What's the reason for using such syntax (0, _.Em)();

Tags: javascript, syntax, google-plus-one

While investigating google plusone scripts, I've seen following syntax many times:

```
(0, _.Em)();
```

Assuming `_.Em` is a function the statement above would result in calling that function, that's pretty obvious. If, on the other hand, it would be undefined, wouldn't the result be the same as doing simply `_.Em()` ?

Can anyone shed a light on what's idea behind using such syntax?

Comment: see also [Does the comma operator influence the execution context in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36076794/1048572)

Comment: see also [Why does google main page use (0, obj.func)(args) syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19535601/1048572)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically, this syntax allows to call `_.Em()` in the context of the `window` object instead of `_`.

Assuming you have this code:

```
Foo = function() {
    this.foo = "foo";
};

Foo.prototype.Em = function() {
    alert(this.foo);
};

var _ = new Foo();
```

Issuing `_.Em()` will result in `Em()` being called in the context of `_`. Inside the function, the `this` keyword will refer to `_`, so `foo` will be printed.

Issuing `(0, _.Em)()` decouples the method call from the object and performs the call in the global context. Inside the function, the `this` keyword will refer to `window`, so `undefined` will be printed, since `window` does not have a `foo` property.

You can test the difference between the two syntaxes in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yqdwS/).

Comment: Because evaluating `_.Em` then applying the call operator is not the same as calling `_.Em()` directly. Evaluating `_.Em` independently returns a "free function", for lack of a better term, and that function will not be tied to the `_` object anymore. The same result can be obtained by writing `var f = _.Em; f();`. In both cases, the `this` keyword will refer to `window` instead of `_` inside the function.

Comment: +1, good answer.  I'd like to add that this is perhaps the most pointless form of syntactic sugaring that I've ever seen in JS. `(0, )()` is exactly the same length as `.call()`, so there's no byte saving unless you remove the space after the comma (and even then it's only one).  At the cost of confusing unsuspecting developers, it really doesn't seem worth using syntax like this.

Comment: @Andy, I think it has to do with [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode). In that mode, `_.Em.call()` without arguments will call `Em()` in the context of `undefined`, not `window`, and `_.Em.call(window)` is arguably longer than `(0, _.Em)()`.

Comment: So what is the (0, _.Em) doing to isolate `Em` from `_`? I know that (1,2,3) gives 3 as the result. So it seems like `(_.Em)` and (0, _.Em) should be equivalent, but `(_.Em)()` behaves just like `_.Em()` so they are clearly not the same.  Also, fwiw in Chrome, the fiddle example reported `undefined`, not `window`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: you're completely right, I had forgotten about that.  I'd still rather use `.call(this)`, but I guess scripts like Google's Plus One script needs to save all the bytes it can.

Comment: @Devon, yup, that's not just Chrome. As I said in my answer, `undefined` will be printed because `this.foo` is evaluated, not just `this` (which would print `[object Window]`). Now, `(0, _.Em)` is not the same as `(_.Em)`, as the comma operator is involved, so `_.Em` is returned as a free function before the call operator is seen. `(_.Em)` is equivalent to `_.Em` because a single expression between parentheses is always equivalent to that expression.

Comment: @Andy, ah, but what if the caller does not operate in the global context? In that case `this` won't refer to `window` in the caller, and `.call(this)` will relay that object as the callee's context.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: yes, of course, there's that too. I was simply stating that I would still choose the more verbose option for clarity.

Comment: Actually it's in the context of `undefined`, only in sloppy-mode function it falls back to the global object.