# What's the purpose of `root=...` code in Async library?

Tags: javascript

There's this snippet of code in the [Async library](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/lib/async.js#L16-L24):

```
if (typeof window == 'object' && this === window) {
    root = window;
}
else if (typeof global == 'object' && this === global) {
    root = global;
}
else {
    root = this;
}
```

Is there any reason for all this code? Why didn't author just use `root = this`?

The first condition is only valid when `this === window`, so `root = window` and `root = this` should be equivalent. Same thing in the second condition, where `root = global` should be equivalent to `root = this`.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: [I asked the author](https://twitter.com/DenysSeguret/status/606427206806568960). He'll probably give a better answer than mine ;)

Answer (score 7):

Not only it is redundant, it also seems to be buggy.

Just before your snippet, there's this :

```
// global on the server, window in the browser
var root, previous_async;
```

So the goal is to assign to `root` the global object.

Such a library should be coded to work in strict mode (not only in strict mode but it should at least be compliant). And in strict mode, the context of an IIFE execution is `undefined`. This code would always fail to find the root object in strict mode, both on node and in the browser.

Note that there are reliable ways to find the root object. The standard one is to do an [indirect call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535601/why-does-google-main-page-use-0-obj-funcargs-syntax):

```
var root = (1,eval)('this');
```

Comment: *not like redundant code*. Can you explain why not? Assuming that strict mode is not supported by the library, this doesn't answer the original question.

Comment: @RGraham "Assuming that strict mode is not supported", this is obviously a redundant code. But assuming this is like assuming this library is obsolete since a very long time. There was an intention justifying so much code and I think I explained it what it was, it's just buggy because it uses `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: But the `use strict` would have to be defined globally for your use case to have been hit, right? Which isn't standard practice I wouldn't have thought. In any case, I don't really have a problem with your answer but I was interested in why exactly the code *is redundant* other than simply "it is".

Comment: @DenysSéguret BTW your code will always fail in Node with `ReferenceError`. Most likely it should not contain `||` at all,  `typeof` checks would be enough

Comment: in Node `window` is not defined, so `this === window` comparison will throw

Comment: @Zhegan Yes, you're right (I removed my previous comment). I fail to see how the existing code looked like a good idea.