# What syntax is this? Is it a es6 syntax?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js

I found this syntax when I read someone's source code of vue ui component.

I guess this might be new es6 syntax but I cannot find the definition from any online es6 resources.

Could anybody enlighten me on that?

Here are some code snippets

```
var _moment = require('moment');
var _moment2 = _interopRequireDefault(_moment);
this.checked.currentMoment = (0, _moment2.default)();
```

The syntax I cannot understand is (0, _moment2.default).

Comment: Looks like regular functions and variables too me ?

Comment: This is "Normal" syntax. I have no clue what the point of the `(0,` is, though.

Comment: Which part of the syntax are you asking about? Because all of this is normal JS. `require` is presumably AMD while the `(0, something)` is also "normal", if a bit strange.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: That's not how "passing parameters" works.

Comment: @Marc  It seems as if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19535601/5647260) offers better explanation.

Comment: This is in order to perform an indirect call, see

Comment: @Cerbrus you are right, when I played with it in jsFiddle It didn't do what I thought..removed false explanation. Cheers :)

Comment: @AndrewLi removed my comment, this was just the first entry I found within 3 seconds of googling ;)

Comment: This is the output from Babel. It likely once was ES6+ code and has been transpiled to this ES5 code