# Why does UglifyJS transpile `someFunction` to `(0, v.someFunction)`?

Tags: javascript, minify, uglifyjs, uglifyjs2

I'm using UglifyJS to transpile a React web app, and I noticed that it seems to wrap a lot of function calls, specifically functions imported from another module/file, with `(0,` and `)`. What is the point of this?

Example: It transpiles this

```
var longVariableName = someFunction(some, arguments)
```

to this

```
var t = (0, v.someFunction)(some, arguments)
```

Comment: Are you sure it's uglify that does this, not babel?

Comment: See also [What's the reason for using such syntax: `(0, _.Em)()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9735424/1048572) in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ensures that the `this` context in `someFunction` is `undefined` just like in the original call, not `v`, as it would be in the method call `v.someFunction(some, arguments)`.